# IE gradient darker than expected

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with a gradient in IE, it is not being displayed as I hoped it would.

I have created a grey gradient button which becomes slightly darker as you hover over it. There are no problems with the way it's displayed in firefox or chrome, it seems to only be an internet explorer problem.

**html:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="button1">
```

**css:**

```
.button1{
    height:26px;  font-family:verdana,arial, helvetica, sans-serif;  font-size:12px;  font-weight:bold;   
    cursor:pointer;  
    padding-left:10px;   padding-right:10px;  margin:2px;  
    border:1px solid #000;   float:left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;   
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    background: rgb(254,255,232); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%, rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,255,232,1)), 
        color-stop(100%,rgba(214,219,191,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,255,232,1) 0%,rgba(214,219,191,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#feffe8', endColorstr='#d6dbbf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.button1:hover{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E6E6E6), to(#fff));/*for webkit*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E6E6,  #fff);/*for firefox*/
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#E6E6E6', endColorstr='#fff',GradientType=0);/*for IE*/  
}
```

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Wg65Y/

Answer (score 0):

IE support for CSS is a nightmare for developers and perhaps worst in case of gradients.

What you need is [CSS3 solutions for Internet Explorer](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/)